# getElementID, can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to learn JavaScript.. and I'm trying to follow examples.. and I can't get this getElementById to work properly... why is it saying Null in the alert box instead of the actual paragraph?

```
<html>
  <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById('excitingText');
    alert(x);
   </script>  
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This is a header!</h1>
    <p id="excitingText">
      This is a paragraph! <em>Excitement</em>!
    </p>
    <p>
      This is also a paragraph, but it is not nearly as exciting as the last one.
    </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

When you execute

```
var x = document.getElementById('excitingText');
    alert(x);
```

the page is not finished loading. Put it inside `window.onload` or put it at the end of the page will make it work. Try:

```
window.onload = function() {
      var x = document.getElementById('excitingText');
                alert(x);
 }
```

Or put it at the end. But it's better to put it inside `window.onload`.

```
<html>
  <head>    

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This is a header!</h1>
    <p id="excitingText">
      This is a paragraph! <em>Excitement</em>!
    </p>
    <p>
      This is also a paragraph, but it is not nearly as exciting as the last one.
    </p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById('excitingText');
    alert(x);
   </script>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the **page** not being done loading. It's specifically because the element being targeted hasn't been rendered. And you shouldn't suggest that `window.onload` is "better" without a reason

Comment: @Ian: I should have used a more precise term like "The html tags are not parsed into DOM objects yet". Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

That is because your script is loaded before the element exists. So try to put it under `window.onload` to ensure it gets executed after the DOM has been loaded. Or move it to the end of the page like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/ycBC2/)**.

Try this:

```
 window.onload = function() {
      var x = document.getElementById('excitingText');
                alert(x);
 }
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RWBf/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the element's reference before it has been placed in the DOM.
Put the same code in "$(document).onload()" and will work

```
$(document).onload(function(){
     var x = document.getElementById('excitingText');
     alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the same in :

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById('excitingText');
      alert(x); 
 });
```

It's the same as other but 1 other way of doing it.